# Implement a union all query with an inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have 2 table like this:

```
//             table1
+-----------------+-----------------+
|       col1      |        id       |
|-----------------+-----------------|
+-----------------+-----------------+
|       test      |        1        |
|-----------------+-----------------|
|       test      |        2        |
|-----------------+-----------------|
|    anything     |        3        |
|-----------------+-----------------|
|    anything     |        4        |
|-----------------+-----------------|


//             table2
+-----------------+-----------------+
|       col1      |        id       |
|-----------------+-----------------|
+-----------------+-----------------+
|       test      |        5        |
|-----------------+-----------------|
|       test      |        6        |
|-----------------+-----------------|
|    anything     |        7        |
|-----------------+-----------------|
|    anything     |        8        |
|-----------------+-----------------|
```

When I use `union all` to get `id` values where `col1` is equal to 'test', result is desired:

```
select * from table1 where col1='test'
union all
select * from table2 where col1='test'

// the result of this code is: 4 rows. id{1,2,5,6}
```

Then, for faster and better performance I implemented it with an `inner join`, but result is not desired:

```
select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t1.col1=t2.col1
where t1.col1='test'

// the result of this code is: 8 rows. id{1-5,1-6,2-5,2-6}
```

How can I use an `inner join` with these tables to get result id{1, 2, 5, 6}?

---

**EDIT**

example:

```
table1 {[col1]=word, [col2]=mean}
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  a  | used when referring to someone or something for the first time in a text or conversation |
|-----|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  a  | used to indicate membership of a class of people or things                               |
|-----|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  x  | xxxxx                                                                                    |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

table2 {[col1]=word, [col2]=mean}
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  a  | the blood group whose red cells carry the A antigen                                      |
|-----|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  x  | xxxxx                                                                                    |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now is it possible to I use `join` and `echo` this? :

```
a | used when referring to someone or something for the first time in a text or conversation
a | used to indicate membership of a class of people or things
a | the blood group whose red cells carry the A antigen
```

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier to combine the tables into a single one, if you need to always treat them as a "fake single"?

Comment: @MarcB what ??? when i use `inner join` instead of `union all`, Search speed increases!

Comment: why is why I'm asking if it wouldn't be smarter to have `single_table` that has the data from both tables, instead of two separate tables that you need to combine with queries anyways?

Comment: *8 rows* ? The join will naturally place the rows adjacent to each other, you should have 4 rows and 4 columns

Comment: @MarcB aha, this is a example, in fact i have 5 table that each of them have more 300,000 rows. I can't create one table.

Comment: @AlexK. you right, i have 4 rows and 4 columns. but i what only 4 rows ..!

Comment: @AlexK. can i write a query to select only 1,2,5,6 using `join` ?

Comment: I actually don't think this is possible. And even if it was the performance might be similar to `union all`. If you're not already using version 5.7.3 or above you might consider switching as there might be some performance improvements regarding certain `union all` statements (cf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-3.html).

Comment: @Marvin when i don't have duplicate rows and the use of `inner join`, output is the same with  `union all`. and time spent = 0.002 !! but when i use `union all`, time spent = 0.02. That's why I want to use `inner join`

Comment: 0.02 seconds is still pretty impressive if you ask me.

Comment: @McAdam331 I have a popular website. I usually have more than 1,000 online users. then at that time performance slows. something like: 2 sec :(

Comment: your problem is that "join" pieces tables together horizontally. if you have 2 tables with 3 columns each, a join will give you a single result "table" with 6 columns. a union joins vertically - 2 tables with 3 columns gives you a 3 column result, with 2x the records.

Comment: @MarcB exactly ..! just what is mean of 2x the records ?

Comment: ok. simple db: 2 tables, 3 fields each, with 10 records each. theoretically speaking, a `join` will give you a result set with 6 fields and 10 records. a `union all` will give you a result set with 3 fields and 20 records (10 from each table).

Comment: @MarcB aha !! got it ...! tnx bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this easily with an inner join. Think about what an inner join does, it places them adjacent to each other based on the related column. For example, if you ran the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table2.col1 = table1.col1 AND table2.col1 = 'test';
```

You would see a result like this:

```
| col1 | id | col1 | id |
+------+----+------+----+
| test | 1  | test | 5  |
| test | 2  | test | 5  |
| test | 1  | test | 6  |
| test | 2  | test | 6  |
```

At this point, you might try to run a query for distinct values from each of the two columns but to the best of my knowledge that is not possible.

So, I don't believe you can replace a `UNION ALL` query with an `INNER JOIN`, or any join for that matter. Even if you preformed a cross join, you will only ever get `table1.id` in its own column, and `table2.id` in a separate column, which results in the same problem as above.

---

**EDIT**

When you use `union all`, you're just combining rows from the table. So if I run the following query:

```
SELECT col1, id
FROM table1
WHERE col1 = 'test'
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, id
FROM table2
WHERE col1 = 'test'
```

You will see this:

```
| col1 | id |
+------+----+
| test | 1  |
| test | 2  |
| test | 5  |
| test | 6  |
```

Because it takes the result set from the two individual queries and combines them together. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48dd5/5) example that shows both queries so you can visually see the difference side by side.

Comment: aha i see, may edit your answer and tell me when i use union all what table made ?

Comment: wow, that is a perfect description. then i can not use join at all ?! in fact i have a dictionary web site, i have 5 source of English words (5 table). then user search in the 5 table and will see results of 5 table. how i can search in 5 table for a word ?

Comment: @stack Follow the same pattern seen above 'SELECT englishWords UNION ALL SELECT spanishWords UNION ALL selectFrenchWords...', You can use more than one `UNION ALL` in a statement.

Comment: As though I have to use `UNION ALL`. but `join` was very faster :(( anyway thx

Comment: @stack not a problem. The only way I can see you using a `JOIN` is *maybe* if you reconsidered how you displayed your data. If you were willing to see the different languages side by side instead of all in one column, but that's tricky too.

Comment: @stack my answer still applies.